# Google Mobile Native Dynamic Maps with MapID - can I stop charges?

Tags: android, android-maps, google-cloud-billing

We used Google Mobile Native Dynamic Maps with MapID and this generated tremendous costs for our account - couple hundreds EUR every day. I know NOW this is a billable API, but did not realized that before and it went to production unnoticed.

We are in the process of preparing an update that will load MapView without MapID, but this will take some time.

In the meantime we need some workaround - I am thinking of deleting given map ID from the console and hoping it will just render default map, but I am unsure if it will stop billing?

Is there any other way we can stop Google from charging us for using MapID? Can it be disabled remotely somehow?